# SweetAlert2 Typescript Webpack Build Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, webpack

I can't figure out why I'm receiving errors when I run the default "webpack" command. I'm able to compile my typescript just fine if I remove "**SweetAlert2**". Any help and fresh eyes are greatly appreciated.

These are the steps I've been running to receive the compile errors.

1. npm install sweetalert2
2. add typings reference to my typescript file
3. import swal from sweetalert2
4. call "swal" function at the top of my typescript file inside a jQuery ready statement
5. run "webpack" command

I then receive the below error in command window

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.js
Module build failed: Error: Final loader (./node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js) didn't return a Buffer or String
    at runLoaders (C:\http\Marketing-Git\NewAmericanPortal_v2\NewAmericanPortal_v2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:303:18)
    at C:\http\Marketing-Git\NewAmericanPortal_v2\NewAmericanPortal_v2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:370:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\http\Marketing-Git\NewAmericanPortal_v2\NewAmericanPortal_v2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:211:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\http\Marketing-Git\NewAmericanPortal_v2\NewAmericanPortal_v2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:218:10)
    at C:\http\Marketing-Git\NewAmericanPortal_v2\NewAmericanPortal_v2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:3
    at context.callback (C:\http\Marketing-Git\NewAmericanPortal_v2\NewAmericanPortal_v2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:121:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
 @ ./Scripts/search.ts 6:20-42
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "new-american-portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "this project will replace the new american marketing project to better serve collateral to our customers.",
  "main": "scripts/entry.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "build-prod": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://tfs01:8080/tfs/Marketing-Git/MarketingServices/_git/NewAmericanPortal"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "new",
    "american",
    "portal",
    "new",
    "american",
    "materials"
  ],
  "author": "Jason Spence",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.2",
    "@types/slick-carousel": "^1.6.32",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "npm": "^6.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.26.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        collateral: __dirname + '/Scripts/collateral.ts',
        commonfunc: __dirname + '/Scripts/common-functions.ts',
        home: __dirname + '/Scripts/home.ts',
        myprofile: __dirname + '/Scripts/my-profile.ts',
        search: __dirname + '/Scripts/search.ts',
        favorite: __dirname + '/Scripts/favorite.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Scripts')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin({ debug: true })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/, use: { loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader' } },
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin()
        ]
    }
}
```

**search.ts**

```
// Refs to external libs
/// <reference path ="../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path ="../node_modules/sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts" />

import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { UtilityFunctionsService } from './src/services/utliity-functions.services';
import { UserActionService } from './src/services/user-action.services';

import { SearchFilterObject } from './src/models/search-filter.interface';

$(function () {

    swal({
        title: 'Error!',
        text: 'Do you want to continue',
        type: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it on Node 14 and it worked. You might just need to update your node version.